# How to store a callback value to a global variable using baucisfetch in backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Below is my code to count the collection and store it in a global variable counter. The problem is that it returns undefined.

```
_getCount : function(role){
            var Users = new collections.Users();
            var counter = 0;
            var self = this;

            Users.baucis(
            {
              conditions: { role : role },
              count: true
            }
          ).then(function (  ) {
                    counter = count;
                    //console.log(counter);
                });
          console.log(counter);
          return counter;

        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `count` variable on the line `counter = count;` is declared nowhere.

You should go with something like :

```
 _getCount : function(role){
        var Users = new collections.Users();
        var counter = 0;
        var self = this;

        Users.baucis(
             {
               conditions: { role : role },
               count: true
             }
        ).then(function (  ) {
             counter = Users.length;
             //console.log(counter);
        });
        console.log(counter);
        return counter;

    },
```

`Users.length` being [underscore method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-length) on collections.

Comment: when using baucis to fetch collections and set count to true. it will automatically respond the length of the collection through count variable that's why i'm assigning it to counter. my problem is how to store it in a global variable counter because once i log it out.it respond undefined if outside the callback function...is their any way to store it?even though i know it's asynchronous.

Comment: Can you try to put a `console.log(arguments)` inside the then callback ?